# Increase/decrease parameter in query parameter $_GET through links

Tags: php, methods, hyperlink, parameters, get

Recently, I started to learn PHP through some course I found on my college website (don't worry, this is not homework, I'm doing this on my own)
and I'm stuck. The assignment goes like this:

> Create a page with two links, one for increasing and one for decreasing parameter 'n' which should be accessed through $_GET query parameter. If 'n' is not set, assume it's value is 4.

So, I tried something like this (just for increasing at first):

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="n" value="4">
      <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

and my PHP code goes like this:

```
<?php
$var = 4;
if(!isset($_GET['n'])) {
    $_GET['n'] = $var;
} else {
    $var = $_GET['n'];
    $var++;
    $_GET['n'] = $var;
}
echo $_GET['n'];
?>
```

But this does not seem to work, at all. I'm guessing the 'n' should automatically change in the URL too. Also, how can I have to "submit" buttons, one for increase, one for decrease?

Can anyone help (with some good instructive explanation if possible) and if it's possible to make it with just HTML links because the course didn't go through forms yet.

Comment: On my college, you can access all subjects and lectures for free, with free material. So I'm not actually taking this course but doing it besides my main courses. And yes, this is a quote of the assignment. If you want, I can provide links, but it's in Croatian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code could be simplified to the following:

```
if (!isset($_GET['n'])) {
    $_GET['n'] = 4;
}
$_GET['n']++; // you can do that
```

However, you probably won't want to increment or decrement `$_GET['n']` directly. Try keeping just the `if` part, then incrementing or decrementing when you output the link:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['n'])) {
        $_GET['n'] = 4;
    }
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?n=" . ($_GET['n'] + 1) ?>">increment n</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?n=" . ($_GET['n'] - 1) ?>">decrement n</a>
```

Note that don't need a form to pass parameters through `$_GET` or `$_POST` — you can just build a URL that passes a parameter, like I did here.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! I didn't know you could pass PHP code as `href` to a link. Thanks again.

Comment: @renato.ruskan no problem, glad it helped! Yep, you can run PHP code anywhere you like, even in the middle of an HTML tag as you can see. Of course you could also output the whole link using `echo` (like `echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?n=' . $_GET['n'] + 1) . '">increment n</a>';`; that's really up to you

Answer (score 1):

in the form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="n" value="<?php echo $var; ?>">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

to make it increase / decrease:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET['n'])) {
    $var = 4;
  } else {
    $var = $_GET['n'];
  }
  echo 'Value = ' . $var;
?>

<p>
  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?n=<?php echo $var+1;?">Increase</a>
  <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?n=<?php echo $var-1; ?>">Decrease</a>
</p>
```